# Postion toolbarbutton in nav-bar with mozilla SDK

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

I recently use the SDK of mozilla to developp an add-on. But when I tested it, I found that the add-on icon is in the add-on bar.

I wanna to move it on the nav-bar at the installation. How can I do that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To resolve the problem. I use a part of the code in [toolbarbutton](https://github.com/voldsoftware/toolbarbutton-jplib).
You just need replace in toolbarbutton.js the line 73 
`($("navigator-toolbox") || $("mail-toolbox")).palette.appendChild(tbb);`

by this code `window.document.getElementById('nav-bar').appendChild(tbb)`.

Now the toolbarbutton is placed on the right of the nav-bar.

[Here](https://builder.addons.mozilla.org/package/150870/latest/) you can find the code example used.

Comment: The Add-on Builder tool was retired on April 1, 2014

Answer (score 1):

If you use this [toolbarbutton](https://github.com/voldsoftware/toolbarbutton-jplib) module then you can move the button by setting the [toolbarID](https://github.com/voldsoftware/toolbarbutton-jplib/blob/master/docs/toolbarbutton.md).

I don't think it's possible to move a widget at the moment.

Comment: Finally I found the solution ^^

Comment: Both links are expired now.